# ResultSet returned closed with ojdbc7 and hibernate 3.2.0 on Oracle 12.1.0.2

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

1. We have a legacy java application which we have to migrate from oracle 11g to 12.1.0.2.
2. The application was using ojdbc14 driver and we had to change it to ojdbc7 otherwise it could not connect to the database.
3. After we changed the ojdbc driver, our Java Application which was using a Hibernate connection to make a call to an oracle function (which returns a ref cursor) stopped working. The symtoms are that a closed resultset is returned from the database.
4. We also have code which is using a ppl connection instead of hibernate and it works fine with a resultset and a ref cursor.

What we've tried so far:

1. We tried to call the database function from the database itself and it returns a full oracle cursor, so it's not a database issue.
2. We tried setting property hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size to a number bigger than the query returns but this also didn't work.

Comment: It is difficult to understand the issue without adding the exception message or the error.

Comment: IIRC, some older versions of Hibernate didn't correctly handle result set lifetimes as required by JDBC (I believe they expected that result sets would be hold over commit, which isn't the default), you may need to update or even upgrade Hibernate, or find if there is a setting that controls this..